# Cell is greater than zero or infinity

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

So I have a double loop through a matrix, which reads the contents of each cell and if the cell's content is greater than zero it does something.  The problem is there are also not real numbers in the matrix, such as Inf.  What I want is the following:

```
 if (Cell < 0 or inf) {do something}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
if (Cell < 0 || is.infinite(Cell)) { ... }
```

Similarly to the code in your question, this checks whether the number is *less than zero*; it is trivial to change the condition to check whether the numer is *greater than zero*.